# How to send and receive data in mpi c++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

I am a beginner in MPI programing and I am trying to do a matrix-vector multiplication (Ax=b).
let say A matrix is as follows,

```
            |3  2  5|
matrix A=   |4  3  1|
            |2  4  2|
```

I divided A matrix into two matrix A1 and A2 as follows

```
            |1  2  3|
matrix A1=  |3  2  1|
            |1  2  0|

            |2  0  2|
matrix A2=  |1  1  0|
            |1  2  2|
```

The x vector is,

```
            | 2 |
vector x=   | 1 |
            | 3 |
```

I need to calculate Ax=b such a way that the process number 1 does the A1 * x multiplication and gives C1 and process number 2 does the A2 * x multiplication and gives C2 and at the end the sum of C1 and C2 will be wrapped up in C. when I run the code through cmd it stops working and I don't know what is the problem. I would be really grateful if you could help me to find out what is the problem in code,
here is my code,

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cmath>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<ctime> 
#include<iomanip>
#include<mpi.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<assert.h>

using namespace std;

void Initialise(int **res, int rows, int cols);
void Multiply(int **res, int **A, int **B, int aRows, int aCols, int bRows, int bCols);
void timestamp();




//**********************************************************
/*              |3  2  5|
    matrix A=   |4  3  1|
                |2  4  2|

   matrix A is divided into two matrix A1,A2

                |1  2  3|
    matrix A1=  |3  2  1|
                |1  2  0|

                |2  0  2|
    matrix A2=  |1  1  0|
                |1  2  2|


                | 2 |
    vector x=   | 1 |
                | 3 |


                | 23 |
    C   =       | 14 |
                | 14 |

//*********************************************************
*/


    int main(int argc,char **argv)

     {



    int  id, p;

    MPI_Status status;


// p -> no. of processes

// id -> process id

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);
    cout << p << endl;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);


    if (id == 0)// master
    {
        wtime = MPI_Wtime();


        int aRows = 3;
        int aCols = 3;
        int bRows = 3;
        int bCols = 1;

        int** A = new int*[aRows];
        for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
        {
            A[i] = new int[aCols];
        }
        int** A1 = new int*[aRows];
        for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
        {
            A1[i] = new int[aCols];
        }
        int** A2 = new int*[aRows];
        for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
        {
            A2[i] = new int[aCols];
        }

        int** B = new int*[bRows];
        for (int i = 0; i < bRows; i++)
        {
            B[i] = new int[bCols];
        }

        //***************************************
        A[0][0] = 3;
        A[0][1] = 2;
        A[0][2] = 5;
        A[1][0] = 4;
        A[1][1] = 3;
        A[1][2] = 1;
        A[2][0] = 2;
        A[2][1] = 4;
        A[2][2] = 2;
        B[0][0] = 2;
        B[1][0] = 1;
        B[2][0] = 3;
        //**************************************
        A1[0][0] = 1;
        A1[0][1] = 2;
        A1[0][2] = 3;
        A1[1][0] = 3;
        A1[1][1] = 2;
        A1[1][2] = 1;
        A1[2][0] = 1;
        A1[2][1] = 2;
        A1[2][2] = 0;
        //**************************************
        A2[0][0] = 2;
        A2[0][1] = 0;
        A2[0][2] = 2;
        A2[1][0] = 1;
        A2[1][1] = 1;
        A2[1][2] = 0;
        A2[2][0] = 1;
        A2[2][1] = 2;
        A2[2][2] = 2;
        //*************************************
        B[0][0] = 2;
        B[1][0] = 1;
        B[2][0] = 3;
        //*************************************
        int** C;
        C = new int*[aRows];
        for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
        {
            C[i] = new int[bCols];
        }
        //************************************
        int** C1;
        C1 = new int*[aRows];
        for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
        {
            C1[i] = new int[bCols];
        }
        //************************************
        int** C2;
        C2 = new int*[aRows];
        for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
        {
            C2[i] = new int[bCols];
        }
        //***********************************
        Multiply(C, A, B, aRows, aCols, bRows, bCols);

        for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bCols; j++)
            {
                std::cout << C[i][j] << ' ';
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }

        MPI_Send(&aRows, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&aCols, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&bRows, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&bCols, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        MPI_Send(&aRows, 1, MPI_INT, 2, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&aCols, 1, MPI_INT, 2, 6, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&bRows, 1, MPI_INT, 2, 7, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&bCols, 1, MPI_INT, 2, 8, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        MPI_Send(&A1, aRows*aCols, MPI_INT, 1, 9, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&B , bRows*bCols, MPI_INT, 1, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        MPI_Send(&A2, aRows*aCols, MPI_INT, 2, 11, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&B, bRows*bCols, MPI_INT, 2, 12, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }


      for (id=1;id<3;id++)
        {
        if (id == 1)
        {

            int aRows, aCols, bRows, bCols;

            MPI_Recv(&aRows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("receive data:%d", aRows);
            MPI_Recv(&aCols, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("receive data:%d", aCols);
            MPI_Recv(&bRows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("receive data:%d", bRows);
            MPI_Recv(&bCols, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("receive data:%d", bCols);

            //int s = status.MPI_SOURCE;
            //int t = status.MPI_TAG;

    
            int** A1 = new int*[aRows];
            for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
            {
                A1[i] = new int[aCols];
            }

            int** B = new int*[bRows];
            for (int i = 0; i < bRows; i++)
            {
                B[i] = new int[bCols];
            }

            int** C1 = new int*[bRows];
            for (int i = 0; i < bRows; i++)
            {
                C1[i] = new int[bCols];
            }

            //***********************************************************

            MPI_Recv(&A1, aRows*aCols, MPI_INT, 0, 9, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("receive data:%d", A1);
            MPI_Recv(&B , aRows*aCols, MPI_INT, 0, 10, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("receive data:%d", B);

            Multiply(C1, A1, B, aRows, aCols, bRows, bCols);

            for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bCols; j++)
                {
                    cout << C1[i][j] << endl;

                }
            }
        }



        else
        {
            int aRows, aCols, bRows, bCols;

            MPI_Recv(&aRows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&aCols, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 6, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&bRows, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 7, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            MPI_Recv(&bCols, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 8, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);


            int** A2 = new int*[aRows];
            for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
            {
                A2[i] = new int[aCols];
            }

            int** B = new int*[bRows];
            for (int i = 0; i < bRows; i++)
            {
                B[i] = new int[bCols];
            }

            int** C2 = new int*[bRows];
            for (int i = 0; i < bRows; i++)
            {
                C2[i] = new int[bCols];
            }

            MPI_Recv(&A2, aRows*aCols, MPI_INT, 0, 11, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("receive data:%d", A2);
            MPI_Recv(&B , aRows*aCols, MPI_INT, 0, 12, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            printf("receive data:%d", B);

            //**************************************************************
            MPI_Status status;
            Multiply(C2, A2, B, aRows, aCols, bRows, bCols);
            for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bCols; j++)
                {
                    cout << C2[i][j] << endl;
                }

            }
        }
        //MPI_Recv(&(C1[0][0]), aRows*bCols, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

void Multiply(int **res, int **A, int **B, int aRows, int aCols, int bRows, int bCols)
{
    if (aCols != bRows)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bCols; j++)
        {
            res[i][j] = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < aCols; k++)
            {
                res[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}

void Initialise(int **res, int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            res[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to run this as a two-process session, right? In that case,
`MPI_Send(&aRows, 1, MPI_INT, 2, 5, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` etc.
do not seem correct as process-ids/ ranks start from 0.

Comment: The matrices are not contiguous

Comment: What does that mean?